# Login application using xAuthToken , spring redis and security

Tags: angular, spring, redis

I am new in angular and trying to develop a login application using spring boot, redis, spring security and Angular. I am following an Angular 2 tutorial while using Angular 5 and tried to convert all the code into Angular 5. Even though I converted most of the code, I couldn't convert `localStorage.setItem("xAuthToken", res.json().token);` line
since this code was related to Http of Angular 2. My question is what is the equivalent of it? Below are what I did till now.

### loging.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  sendCredential(username: string, password: string) {

    //console.log("User -- > "+username,+"Pass -- > "+password);
    let url = "http://localhost:8181/token";
    let encodedCredentials = btoa(username + ":" + password);
    let basicHeader = "Basic " + encodedCredentials;
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Authorization': basicHeader
    });

    return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers });

  }

 checkSession() {
    let url = "http://localhost:8181/checkSession";

    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'x-auth-token': localStorage.getItem('xAuthToken')
    });

    return this.http.get(url, { headers: headers });
  }
}
```

#### login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {LoginService} from '../../services/login.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  private credential = {'username':'', 'password' : ''};
  private loggedIn = false;

  constructor(private loginService: LoginService) { }

  onSubmit() {
    this.loginService.sendCredential(this.credential.username, this.credential.password).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
        localStorage.setItem("xAuthToken", res.json().token);
            this.loggedIn = true;
            location.reload();
        },
        error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginService.checkSession().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.loggedIn=true;
        },
        error => {
            this.loggedIn=false;
        }
    );
  }

}
```

I am getting error:

> Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object' with existing code.

Comment: In angular5 results are already formatted in json format so all you have to do is pass the token value itself as second parameter. No need to use json() method.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this, and it will be resolved:

```
localStorage.setItem("xAuthToken", res.token);
```

Answer (score -1):

localStorage.setItem("xAuthToken", JSON.stringify(res));   "Appaji "  This is pakka answer